# onBackPressed() doesn't trigger when showing ProgressDialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have tried a lot of ways to trigger the `backPressed`() event when the `progressDialog` is displayed. But none works. If I provide `progDialog.setcancelable(true);` I am able to dismiss the `progressDialog` but still the `onBackPressed`() doesn't get triggered.

Comment: The onBackPessed method of which class would you expect to trigger ? AlertDialog ?

Comment: No, my activity has its own onBackPressed() event.

Comment: yes, of course I have overrided it

Comment: D'you want onBackPressed triggered the same time progressDialog is dismissed, in other words on press causes two operations?

Comment: No, I want to dismiss the progressDialog by pressing the back button

Comment: @Andro have a look on my answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When ProgressDialog is active if yiou press back key to perform yopur own operations you have to set `setOnCancelListener` to the progressdialog.
write your logic inside `onCancel()` method example the whole logic that you have written in onBackPressed() event those things you have to write here.

### Sample code

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;

public class CancelProgressDialog extends Activity {

    ProgressDialog myProgressDialog = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

        super.onCreate(icicle);

        /* Create a very simple button */

        Button b = new Button(this);

        this.setContentView(b);

        b.setText("Show ProgressBar...");

        b.setOnClickListener(myProgressBarShower);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("...any key is pressed....");
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
            System.out.println("...BackButton is pressed...");
            if( (myProgressDialog!= null) && myProgressDialog.isShowing()){
                myProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    /** OnClickListener that fakes some work to be done. */

    OnClickListener myProgressBarShower = new OnClickListener() {

        // @Override

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // Display an indeterminate Progress-Dialog

            myProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(CancelProgressDialog.this,

            "Please wait...", "Doing Extreme Calculations...", true);
            myProgressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

                public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("...cancel button is pressed");
//                  perform your task here
                }
            });
            myProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);



        }



    };

}
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: Sorry my friend.. This is not working. No key event is detected while ProgressDialog is showing.

Comment: please check my once again. no key event will be detected but your control goes to onCancel() method. you have to write the code there

Comment: ok. Cool. I was missing the last line `myProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);`. It works now. Thanks.